# Re-enable bitlocker encryption

Tags: windows-8

How do you get the bitlocker encryption active again in Windows 8? I want the gold padlook icon back?

I don't want to remove it or decrypt the drive.

Comment: Are you running Windows 8 Pro?

Comment: yeah I was, now just use truecrypt